# Display a line in matplotlib, so that my results match up with my textbook

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, scikit-learn, line

I'm following along in a ML textbook: Mastering Machine Learning with scikit-learn, and while my code gives me the correct answers, it doesn't match up with what's in the book.

First it gives me this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
X = [[6], [8], [10], [14],   [18]]
y = [[7], [9], [13], [17.5], [18]]
plt.figure()
plt.title('Pizza price plotted against diameter')
plt.xlabel('Diameter in inches')
plt.ylabel('Price in dollars')
plt.plot(X, y, 'k.')
plt.axis([0, 25, 0, 25])
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Which gives me this chart in matplotlib:

[image]

And that matches up with my results.

However, in the next step it gives me this code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
# Training data
X = [[6], [8], [10], [14],   [18]]
y = [[7], [9], [13], [17.5], [18]]
# Create and fit the model
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, y)
print 'A 12" pizza should cost: $%.2f' % model.predict([12])[0]
```

And this chart:

[image]

That chard doesn't match up with my code, it doesn't have the matplotlib chart-maker function. I tried to read guides and make my own:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


X = [[6], [8], [10], [14],   [18]]
y = [[7], [9], [13], [17.5], [18]]


model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, y)

z = np.array([12]).reshape(-1,1)

print ('A 12" pizza should cost: $%.2f' % model.predict(z)[0])
print ("\n" + "_" * 50 + "\n")

plt.figure()
plt.title('Pizza price plotted against diameter')
plt.xlabel('Diameter in inches')
plt.ylabel('Price in dollars')
plt.plot(X, y, z, 'k.')
plt.axis([0, 25, 0, 25])
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

But that just gave me this weird blue thing:

[image]

I'm new to working with math in python, so if anyone could give me more information on how to solve this, it would be appreciated.

Comment: how's the book "Mastering Machine Learning with scikit-learn" was it helpful for you?

Comment: So. Many. Errors.

Comment: Really? I was looking for a book in ML with scikit; too bad

Comment: Actually, this wasn't in the book. By all means read it, it's still the best book I've read on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "weird blue thing" you get is your data joined together by line segments; your data should be plotted using `plt.scatter` which gives you a cloud of points.

Your calculation of the regression line is correct, what needs to be fixed is how to plot that line over your data set:

After fitting your data, you need to extract the values necessary to draw the regression line; the data you need are two points at each extremities of the x-axis (here, `x=0` and `x=25`). if we call `model.predict` on these two values, we obtain the corresponding predictions. These x values coupled with their corresponding predictions form two points that we will use to plot the line.

First we extract the predicted values `y0` and `y25`. We then use `plt.plot` with the points (0, y0) and (25, y25) to draw the regression line in green.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


X = [[6], [8], [10], [14],   [18]]
y = [[7], [9], [13], [17.5], [18]]


model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, y)

z = np.array([12]).reshape(-1,1)

print ('A 12" pizza should cost: $%.2f' % model.predict(z)[0])
print ("\n" + "_" * 50 + "\n")

plt.figure()
plt.title('Pizza price plotted against diameter')
plt.xlabel('Diameter in inches')
plt.ylabel('Price in dollars')
plt.scatter(X, y, z, 'k')

y0, y25 = model.predict(0)[0][0], model.predict(25)[0][0]
plt.plot((0, 25), (y0, y25), 'g')

plt.axis([0, 25, 0, 25])
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: unless you are scaling the markers by size or color using plot with no line ex `ax.plot(x, y, 'o')` gives slightly better performance (only really matters when you have large numbers of points)

Comment: also, can't you vectorize calls to `predict`?

Comment: @Reblochon Masque - why do you write z = np.array([12]).reshape(-1,1)? should it be simply z=12? wonder if there's a reason for this; thanks

Comment: Good question. IDK - that is from the OP's code, maybe he had a good reason for using that and it was left in the simplified code he posted? Because it did not affect the solution to his problem, I did not give it a second thought.